# Alternatives for $~ \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{ 0 \right\} ~$The set of integers each of which is greater or equal than zero

Tags: notation

$~ \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{ 0 \right\} ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{The set of integers each of which is greater or equal than zero}  ~$

I want to know or create the alternative(s) of set of $~ \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{ 0 \right\}  ~$

As I write $~ \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{ 0 \right\}  ~$  using a pen in a paper, then a symbol of $~ \cup  ~$ may sometimes be seen as letter U and the ambiguity seems happens.

Does anyone know it?

**Add**

Thought that $~ \mathbb Z_{\geq 0} ~$ may be the one of the answers .

Comment: Here's a joke answer that's technically correct: $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\sin(\pi x)=0\text{ and }x\geq 0\}$.

Comment: [N.G. de Bruijn suggests](https://vixra.org/pdf/1208.0223v1.pdf) using $\Bbb N_0$ for $\{0, 1, 2,3\ldots\}$  and $\Bbb N_1$ for $\{1, 2, 3\ldots\}$.  (Page 4.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen $\mathbb N_0$ for this purpose.

However, I would simply include $0$ in $\mathbb N$ if that’s more useful. Then, using $\mathbb N^*$ for the set without $0$ is not uncommon, I think.

In any case, you should make your conventions explicit in the text, especially if the precise choice is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

There's no real standard.  Often, authors simply consider $\mathbb{N}$ to include $0$ when the context renders it convenient to do so.  In some contexts (especially set theory), authors may use $\omega$.  As long as your audience understands what you mean, it does not matter much.

Answer (score 3):

I take it you mean alternative notations, not alternative sets.

You can write $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}={}$the set of all finite cardinal numbers. (A cardinal number is an answer to "How many?".)

Or $\mathbb Z^{\ge\,0}.$

Comment: Can I also write $~ \mathbb Z_{\ge 0} ~$ as $~\mathbb Z^{\ge\,0}~$ ?

Comment: @bostondynamicslover : I would take either of those to mean $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}. \qquad$